# How can I implement CSS files in EJS

Tags: javascript, ejs

So my workspace structure is like this:

[image]

How can I implement now, that I can use the styles.css inside the header.ejs?

Currently, it looks like this:

Dashboard.ejs

```
<%- include("partials/header", { bot, user, path, title: "Dashboard" }) %>
```

Header.ejs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css">
```

Dashboard.js

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + `/assets`));
```

Comment: not enough info, how do you serve the css files? please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an ejs file which requires a server.
The instance of server runs on a base path (generally where the main server file is located).

So in your EJS file you need to link your css file relative to the server path.

In your case (assuming `dashboard.js` is your main file) you need to use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/styles.css">
```

in your `header.ejs` file.

Keep in mind the `assets` folder and `index.js` are assumed to be in same parent directory.

Comment: Right, but what do I have to put into the dashboard.js to get this link working?

Comment: You would not need anything else in dashboard except setting the static directory.
If you are using express server,
`const express=require('express');`
`const app = express();`
`app.use(express.static(__dirname));`
then in your _header.ejs_ you can use
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">`

Comment: For security I would recommend
`const path=require('path');`
`...`
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'assets')));`

then in header.ejs
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">`

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Your answer is the solution.
I was just a bit braindead and typed style.css instead of styles.css...